# Jet API marketplace with Magento

Tags: api, magento, magento-1.9

I want to connect Magento with Jet marketplace API.

Jet provides API for the same.

I have an extension that is configured on my website.

Just finish 80% profile in my Jet.com profile.

Now for 20% i have to complete TEST API as per jet.com criteria.

```
{
  "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

I got token successfully. I'm using POSTMAN tool for sending requests.

Now how can i use token for sku upload and further price and image uploading ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have some code your using already?

Comment: Its really easy to write these in classes and convert the class to json.https://developer.jet.com/docs/merchant-sku

Comment: I'm using Postman as a tool.

Comment: Any way as of now it works smoothly. No error. There was a text problem in in authorisation text while sending request.

Comment: These issue generally happen due to typo in API user or secret key assuming that the API calling and header information part was done correctly

Comment: thanks @CedCommerce for your input

Answer (score 1):

For completing test apis , you have to upload a product (post three files : merchantsku , price and inventory feed files with file parser method) to jet via api , after uploading product you have to create a order from jet partner panel , fetch the order as well acknowledge the order and then you have to ship one order and cancel one order , your test api will be configured and will complete and when you reload your jet partner panel your live apis will be activated.

For the error which you asked :

```
 {
  "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Your test apis details are not correct or you are not sending in a correct way , if you are using Postman then you have to set in headers
Authorization: Bearer "token";

For getting token you can use below post api :

```
$url= https://merchant-api.jet.com/api/token;
$postFields='{"user":"'.$usr.'","pass":"'.$pass.'"}';
```

and you can use this token in all jet api calls.
Hope this will help.